# Concerning the package name and RAW resources for Android App

Tags: android, video, resources

I had a situation where I needed to create an alternate version of an app already written and compiled.  I changed the package name;  that's what I'm calling it, I'm referring to the "com.examplename.appname".

So the original name was something like:
com.examplename.appname
In the new app, I changed it to:
com.examplename.appnamenew

So far so good.  The app compiles and runs fine.  But there is a video referenced in the app at that resource name:  (I don't remember the syntax)
uri = com.examplename.appname & "/Raw/video.mp4"

I didn't change that resource name because I figured it wouldn't matter if the resource is the same, because it compiles that RAW clip into the program.

It turns out, it does matter.  If you have the OLD version and the NEW version on the same device at the same time, the NEW version runs fine (resource exists).  But if you uninstall the OLD version, the NEW version cannot find the video.  This is because the resource referenced in the compiled program is missing.

I changed the NEW version to point at the correct local resource, which solved the problem, of course.

But why is it that that happened at all?  Why doesn't the video clip compile into the APK?  Or does it, but still requires that resource pointer to be correct?
More importantly, is this some sort of error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why doesn't the video clip compile into the APK?

It did, by your own admission ("I changed the NEW version to point at the correct local resource, which solved the problem, of course").

> Or does it, but still requires that resource pointer to be correct?

If you have a Web site, located at `http://www.durbnpoisn.com`, and you move that Web site to `http://www.durbnpoisn.org`, all references to the original domain name will still work... until you take down the original domain name. Then those references break. Just because you change a domain name on your site does not somehow magically change all inbound URLs from the rest of the Internet.

In your case, you appear to have been using the `android.resource://` `Uri` scheme. That stipulates a package. This is equivalent to the domain name in the URLs above. You changed the package name. References to the old package name will continue to work, though, so long as the old package was still around. Once you removed the old package, references to it would go away. Just because you change a package name does not somehow magically change all inbound references to the old package name from any place that has such a reference.

The same holds true for any place where you are hard-coding a package name. Hence, don't hard-code package names, but use other approaches (worst case: call `getPackageName()` on a handy `Context`, like your `Activity`).

Comment: I think you're right that the mistake was hardcoding the reference rather than pulling the resources at runtime.  I was just confused as to why that pointer is still necessary once the program is compiled.  It's built in at that point.  Why the need for the pointer?

Comment: @durbnpoisn: "Why the need for the pointer?" -- you have to ask yourself that question, as you were the one who created the "pointer" in the first place. If my guess is correct, and this was triggered by the use of `android.resource://`, there is no Lint warning for using that scheme, or for hard-coding a package name. As you discovered, any app can read any other app's resources, and so what you had might be intentional. Hence, the assumption is that you know what you're doing by using `android.resource://` and a hard-coded package name.

Comment: THAT was the answer I was really looking for.  That any package can reference any other package!  I didn't know that.  I was surprised to have discovered it, because I thought what I had found was a rather odd security flaw.  Evidently it is intentional by design.  So that really does settle the matter for me.  Thanks!

Comment: @durbnpoisn: "Evidently it is intentional by design" -- which doesn't mean that it's not a security flaw. :-) It's a little known aspect of Android that resources are effectively world-readable. That's in support of things like home screen launchers and activity choosers, which need to get at icons and strings associated with your activities.